# How can I provide a link to display my account details by clicking on account name using lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have created a search bar using lightning component displaying the details of account searchable by account name. But I need to make the changes. I want to be searched by account name but it should give the details only on clicking the account name. My code is as follows
**searchAccountController.apxc**

```
public class searchAccountController {

 @AuraEnabled
 public static List < account > fetchAccount(String searchKeyWord)
 {
  String searchKey = searchKeyWord + '%';
  List < Account > returnList = new List < Account > ();
  List < Account > lstOfAccount = [select id, Name, Type, Industry, Phone, Fax from account
                               where Name LIKE: searchKey LIMIT 500];

  for (Account acc: lstOfAccount)
 {
   returnList.add(acc);
  }
  return returnList;
 }
}
```

**searchAccount.cmp**

```
<!-- CREATE ATTRIBUTE/VARIABLE-->
<aura:attribute name="searchResult" type="List" description="use for store and display account list return from server"/>
<aura:attribute name="searchKeyword" type="String" description="use for store user search input"/>
<aura:attribute name="Message" type="boolean" default="false" description="use for display no record found message"/>
<aura:attribute name="TotalNumberOfRecord" type="integer" default="0" description="use for display Number of records"/>

<!-- SHOW LOADING SPINNER--> 
<lightning:spinner variant="brand" size="large" aura:id="Id_spinner" class="slds-hide" />

<div class="slds-m-around_medium">
   <!-- SEARCH INPUT --> 
    <lightning:layout>
        <lightning:layoutItem size="3" padding="around-small">
            <lightning:input value="{!v.searchKeyword}"
                             required="true"  placeholder="Search"
                             onkeyup="{!c.Search}"
                             aura:id="searchField"
                             label="Account Name"/>
        </lightning:layoutItem>
                </lightning:layout>


    <!-- ERROR MESSAGE IF NOT RECORDS FOUND--> 
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.Message}">
        <div class="slds-notify_container slds-is-relative">
            <div class="slds-notify slds-notify_toast slds-theme_error" role="alert">
                <div class="slds-notify__content">
                    <h2 class="slds-text-heading_small">No Records Found...</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </aura:if>


     <aura:iteration items="{!v.searchResult}" var="acc" indexVar="count">



                        <div class="slds-truncate">{!acc.Name}</div>

                        <div class="slds-truncate">{!acc.Type}</div>

                        <div class="slds-truncate">{!acc.Industry}</div>

                        <div class="slds-truncate">{!acc.Phone}</div>

                        <div class="slds-truncate">{!acc.Fax}</div>

            </aura:iteration>

</div>
```

**searchAccountController.js**

```
({
    Search: function(component, event, helper) 
    {
        var searchField = component.find('searchField');

        var isValueMissing = searchField.get('v.validity').valueMissing;
        // if value is missing show error message and focus on field

         if(isValueMissing) {
       // searchField.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();

          searchField.focus();
        }else{
          // else call helper function 
            helper.SearchHelper(component, event);
        }
    },
})
```

**searchAccountHelper.js**

```
({
    SearchHelper: function(component, event) {
        // show spinner message
         component.find("Id_spinner").set("v.class" , 'slds-show');
        var action = component.get("c.fetchAccount");
        action.setParams({
            'searchKeyWord': component.get("v.searchKeyword")
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
           // hide spinner when response coming from server 
            component.find("Id_spinner").set("v.class" , 'slds-hide');
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                var storeResponse = response.getReturnValue();

                // if storeResponse size is 0 ,display no record found message on screen.
                if (storeResponse.length == 0) {
                    component.set("v.Message", true);
                } else {
                    component.set("v.Message", false);
                }

                // set numberOfRecord attribute value with length of return value from server
                component.set("v.TotalNumberOfRecord", storeResponse.length);

                // set searchResult list with return value from server.
                component.set("v.searchResult", storeResponse); 

            }else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                alert('Response is Incompleted');
            }else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        alert("Error message: " + 
                                errors[0].message);
                    }
                } else {
                alert("Unknown error");
                }
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
})
```

Comment: You can directly return the list `lstOfAccount` no need to iterate over this list add each item to the new list and then return the new list both will do the same thing. And you can return the SOQL directly even no need to add the records into a list.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at recordViewForm, you can add this to your component and pass an Id to it on click so it would display the things you want to show. Easiest is to create a new component, specifically having just this form and 1 attribute with an Id of the record so you can pass it easily and clear on search. Take a look at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordViewForm/documentation

Answer (score 0):

Well Idea here is to pass a data-attribute to the div element showing account name and trigger a function on click of the div to get the id.

Suggested Imporvements:

- In apex return only ids
- Avoid duplicate list creation
- SOQL are time taking, fire only after 3 characters have been entered; else the returned records will be too high and will take longer response time as payload will be more
- use action.setStorable to improve the performance

**Apex Code:**
No change

**Helper Method:**
No Change

**searchAccountController.js:**

```
({
    Search: function(component, event, helper) 
    {
        var searchField = component.find('searchField');

        var isValueMissing = searchField.get('v.validity').valueMissing;
        // if value is missing show error message and focus on field

        if(isValueMissing) {
            // searchField.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();

            searchField.focus();
        }else{
            // else call helper function 
            helper.SearchHelper(component, event);
        }
    },


    displayDetails: function(component, event, helper){
        var accountId = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
        component.set("v.accId",accountId);
    }
})
```

**searchAccount.cmp**

```
<aura:component controller="searchAccountController">
<!-- CREATE ATTRIBUTE/VARIABLE-->
<aura:attribute name="searchResult" type="List" description="use for store and display account list return from server"/>
<aura:attribute name="searchKeyword" type="String" description="use for store user search input"/>
<aura:attribute name="Message" type="boolean" default="false" description="use for display no record found message"/>
<aura:attribute name="TotalNumberOfRecord" type="integer" default="0" description="use for display Number of records"/>
<aura:attribute name="accId" type="ID"/> 
<!-- SHOW LOADING SPINNER--> 
<lightning:spinner variant="brand" size="large" aura:id="Id_spinner" class="slds-hide" />

<div class="slds-m-around_medium">
    <!-- SEARCH INPUT --> 
    <lightning:layout>
        <lightning:layoutItem size="3" padding="around-small">
            <lightning:input value="{!v.searchKeyword}"
                             required="true"  placeholder="Search"
                             onkeyup="{!c.Search}"
                             aura:id="searchField"
                             label="Account Name"/>
        </lightning:layoutItem>
    </lightning:layout>


    <!-- ERROR MESSAGE IF NOT RECORDS FOUND--> 
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.Message}">
        <div class="slds-notify_container slds-is-relative">
            <div class="slds-notify slds-notify_toast slds-theme_error" role="alert">
                <div class="slds-notify__content">
                    <h2 class="slds-text-heading_small">No Records Found...</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </aura:if>


    <aura:iteration items="{!v.searchResult}" var="acc" indexVar="count">

        <div class="slds-truncate" data-id="{!acc.Id}" onclick="{!c.displayDetails}">{!acc.Name}</div>

    </aura:iteration>
    <p>Details Area</p>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.accId != null}">
        <lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!v.accId}" objectApiName="Account">
                <div class="slds-box">
                    <lightning:outputField fieldName="Name" />
                    <lightning:outputField fieldName="Type" />
                    <lightning:outputField fieldName="Industry" />
                    <lightning:outputField fieldName="Phone" />
                </div>
        </lightning:recordViewForm> 
    </aura:if>

</div>
```

**ScreenShot:**
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code.

searchAccount.cmp

```
<aura:component controller="searchAccountController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <aura:attribute name="searchResult" type="List" description="use for store and display account list return from server"/>
    <aura:attribute name="searchKeyword" type="String" description="use for store user search input"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Message" type="boolean" default="false" description="use for display no record found message"/>
    <aura:attribute name="TotalNumberOfRecord" type="integer" default="0" description="use for display Number of records"/>
    <lightning:navigation aura:id="navigate" />
    <!-- SHOW LOADING SPINNER--> 
    <lightning:spinner variant="brand" size="large" aura:id="Id_spinner" class="slds-hide" />
    
    
    <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
        <!-- SEARCH INPUT --> 
        <lightning:layout>
            <lightning:layoutItem size="3" padding="around-small">
                <lightning:input value="{!v.searchKeyword}"
                                 required="true"  placeholder="Search"
                                 onkeyup="{!c.Search}"
                                 aura:id="searchField"
                                 label="Account Name"/>
            </lightning:layoutItem>
        </lightning:layout>
        
        
        <!-- ERROR MESSAGE IF NOT RECORDS FOUND--> 
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.Message}">
            <div class="slds-notify_container slds-is-relative">
                <div class="slds-notify slds-notify_toast slds-theme_error" role="alert">
                    <div class="slds-notify__content">
                        <h2 class="slds-text-heading_small">No Records Found...</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </aura:if>
        
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.searchResult}" var="acc" indexVar="count">
            
            <div class="slds-truncate"><a href="#" tabindex="-1" id="{!acc.Id}" onclick="{!c.navigate}">{!acc.Name}</a></div>
            
            <div class="slds-truncate">{!acc.Type}</div>
            
            <div class="slds-truncate">{!acc.Industry}</div>
            
            <div class="slds-truncate">{!acc.Phone}</div>
            
            <div class="slds-truncate">{!acc.Fax}</div>
            
        </aura:iteration>
        
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

searchAccountController.js

```
({
    Search: function(component, event, helper) 
    {
        var searchField = component.find('searchField');
        
        var isValueMissing = searchField.get('v.validity').valueMissing;
        // if value is missing show error message and focus on field
        
        if(isValueMissing) {
            // searchField.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
            
            searchField.focus();
        }else{
            // else call helper function 
            helper.SearchHelper(component, event);
        }
    },
    
    navigate : function(component, event, helper) {
        var id = event.target.id;
        var nagigateLightning = component.find('navigate');
        
        var pageReference = {
            "type": "standard__recordPage",
            "attributes": {
                "recordId": id,
                "objectApiName": 'Account',//place your record id here that you wish to open
                "actionName": "view"
            }
        };
        
        nagigateLightning.navigate(pageReference);
        
    }    
})
```

Comment: Welcome to the Salesforce Stackexchange platform. Thanks for your answer. Please review the "How do I write a good answer" post here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer  make updates to your answer accordingly.